# how to send a marksheet in email from an excel file using python

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x

I wanted to extract the marks, name and roll number from an excel file and send it in email to the student's email which is also in the excel file. Each row contains details of different students with their email. I want to mail their details in their email from each row.The code below doesn't send any emails. What do I have to do to send the emails? I'm running python 3.6.

Image of different of the excel file
[image]
This is the python code I'm trying to run

```
import smtplib

from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from openpyxl import load_workbook

gmail_user = "username@gmail.com"
gmail_appPassword = "password"

msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
sent_from = ['username@gmail.com']
msg['Subject'] = 'Marksheet'

#excel-file=data
def list_marks():    

    excelfile = 'simple_excelmail.xlsx'
    wb = load_workbook(excelfile)
    ws = wb[wb.sheetnames[0]]

    excel_list = []

    for row in ws.iter_rows(row_offset=1):
        for cell in row:
#            print(cell.value)
            excel_list.append(str(cell.value))

    return excel_list

# Marks is Constructor. Builds template rows for html
class Marks:    

    def __init__(self, name, roll_num, maths, physics, chemistry, english, computer_sci, result):
        self.name = name
        self.roll_num = roll_num
        self.maths = maths
        self.physics = physics
        self.chemistry = chemistry
        self.english = english
        self.computer_sci = computer_sci
        self.result = result
        self.total = 0

        self.template_array = []


#        sum amounts for total
        for i in range(0, len(self.roll_num)):
            self.total += int(self.maths[i]+self.physics[i]+self.chemistry[i]+self.english[i]+self.computer_sci[i])

            template = """
                <tr class="left">
                    <td style="padding: 10px; text-align: left;">"""+ self.roll_num[i] +"""</td>
                    <td style="padding: 10px;">""" + self.maths[i] + """</td>
                    <td style="text-align: right; padding: 10px;">"""+ self.physics[i] +"""</td>
                    <td style="padding-left: 20px;">"""+ self.chemistry[i] +"""</td>
                    <td style="padding-left: 20px;">"""+ self.english[i] +"""</td>
                    <td style="padding-left: 20px;">"""+ self.computer_sci[i] +"""</td>
                    <td style="padding-left: 20px;">"""+ self.total[i] +"""</td>
                    <td style="padding-left: 20px;">"""+ self.result[i] +"""</td>
                    </tr>
                """        
            self.template_array.append(template)
        self.total = str(self.total)



def send_email(to, msg, new_template):

    data.reverse()    

    for i in range(0, 9):
        data.pop()

    try:
        data.reverse()
        server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com', 465)
        server.login(gmail_user, gmail_pword)
        server.sendmail(sent_from, to, msg.as_string())

        print("Email Sent To: ", new_template.name)
        print("@: ", to)            
        print("Roll Number: ", new_template.roll_num)
        print("TOTAL: ", new_template.total, "---------------------------")            
        server.quit()

        if(data[0] == 'None'):
            print('END OF LIST')
        else:            
            build_email(data)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        print('Email Failed to Send to: ', new_template.name)
        print("@: ", to)
        print("Roll Numbers: ", new_template.roll_num)

data = list_marks()


def build_email(data):


    new_template = Marks(data[0], data[1], data[2], data[3], data[4], data[5], data[6], data[7])

    to = data[8].split(",") #List of emails

    text = "Hello, {0}, \n Please find the following marks attached {1} on these roll numbers for the following students.\n Thank You.\n ".format(data[0], data[1])


    html = """\
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <body>
            <p style="text-align: center"> Hello, """+ new_template.name +""" Hope this email finds you well.</p> 

            <p style="text-align: center">Here are your marks</p>
            <hr style="width: 500px;">
            <table style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto">
                <tr>
                    <th>Marks TOTAL:</th>
                    <th style="padding-left: 100px">$"""+ new_template.total +"""</th>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <hr class="width">

            <table style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto">
                <tr class="left padded">
                    <th style="text-align: left;"> Roll Number </th>
                    <th> Maths </th>
                    <th style="text-align: right;"> Physics </th>
                    <th style="padding-left: 20px;"> Chemistry</th>
                    <th style="padding-left: 20px;"> English</th>
                    <th style="padding-left: 20px;"> Computer Science</th>
                    <th style="padding-left: 20px;"> Result</th>
                </tr>
                """ + ''.join(new_template.template_array) + """
            </table>

            <hr style="width: 500px;">
                <table style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; padding: 10px;">
                    <tr>
                        <th> Thank You! </th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th> Any School </th>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            <hr style="width: 500px;">

        </body>
    </html>
    """

    part1 = MIMEText(text, 'plain')
    part2 = MIMEText(html, 'html')


    msg.attach(part1)
    msg.attach(part2)

    send_email(to, msg, new_template)  


build_email(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using Python for this, I'd recommend using Excel & Outlook to do the job.  Here is some VBA code that should (pretty much) do what you want.  You will probably need to modify the code slightly, to conform to your specific setup.

```
In column A : Names of the people
In column B : E-mail addresses
In column C:Z : Filenames like this C:\Data\Book2.xls (don't have to be Excel files)
```

The Macro will loop through each row in "Sheet1" and if there is a E-mail address in column B
and file name(s) in column C:Z it will create a mail with this information and send it.

```
Sub Send_Files()
'Working in Excel 2000-2016
'For Tips see: http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/winmail/Outlook/tips.htm
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim FileCell As Range
    Dim rng As Range

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With

    Set sh = Sheets("Sheet1")

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    For Each cell In sh.Columns("B").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)

        'Enter the path/file names in the C:Z column in each row
        Set rng = sh.Cells(cell.Row, 1).Range("C1:Z1")

        If cell.Value Like "?*@?*.?*" And _
           Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(rng) > 0 Then
            Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

            With OutMail
                .to = cell.Value
                .Subject = "Testfile"
                .Body = "Hi " & cell.Offset(0, -1).Value

                For Each FileCell In rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
                    If Trim(FileCell) <> "" Then
                        If Dir(FileCell.Value) <> "" Then
                            .Attachments.Add FileCell.Value
                        End If
                    End If
                Next FileCell

                .Send  'Or use .Display
            End With

            Set OutMail = Nothing
        End If
    Next cell

    Set OutApp = Nothing
    With Application
        .EnableEvents = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With
End Sub
```

https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/amail6.htm